# Взаимодействие между классами

Tags: c++

Добрый день, уважаемые участники форума Хэшкод. Пишу курсовой проект по дисциплине "Теория алгоритмов". Необходимо установить выполнимость / невыполнимость некого множества, используя при этом определенные стратегии. Я начал так: создал два класса variety (множество дизъюнктов для которого необходимо установить выполнимость / невыполнимость) и класс disjunct (непосредственно сам дизъюнкт состоящий из литералов). Объявление классов:

```
class disjunct{
public:
disjunct();
virtual ~disjunct();

bool isEmpty() const;
void addLiteral(signed char literal);
void show() const;
void clear();

private:
list<signed char> disj;
const signed char d;
};

class variety {

public:
variety(disjunct disj);
~variety();

bool isEmpty() const;
void addDisjunct(disjunct disj);
void clear();
void show();

private:
list<disjunct> var;

};
```

У меня есть несколько вопросов по реализации:

1. При удалении класса variety будет ли правильно высвобождена память в классе disjunct. Деструктор там и там вызывает метод clear() класса list;
2. Как правильно взаимодействовать с классом disjunct через класс variety. Например сравнение двух дизъюнктов?
3. В классе disjunct есть переменная d, в принципе она общая для всего класса и изменяться не должна. Как правильно ее объявить static?
4. Описываю метод show() для variety

   ```
   void variety::show(){
   list<disjunct>::const_iterator i;

   for(i = var.begin(); i != var.end(); i++){
       cout<<endl;

       cout<<"Дизъюнкт";

       *i->show();
   }

   }
   ```

Получаю ошибку

> main.cpp:108:18: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

**P.S**
 Скажите пожалуйста как в этом редакторе сделать табуляцию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. да, для них будет вызван деструктор
2. через итератор  получать нужный элемент. Но я бы заменил `list` на `vector`. В этом случае можно будет обращаться по индексу, как к массиву.
3. добавить в начало объявления static?
4. а 108 строка, это какая из них?

Comment: 108 строка, это *i->show(), где show() метод класса disjunct. Я пытаюсь по итератору получить элемент из list<disjunct> var, и вызвать для него метод show()(уже класса disjunct). Он у меня public, не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Похоже там звездочка лишняя, а то получается двойное разименование.