# Ошибка при перегрузке оператора =

Tags: c++

Вопрос является продолжением [данного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/163298/c-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) вопроса. По алгоритму мне необходимо создать новый дизъюнкт на основании двух других и поместить его в конец множества. Для этого в моей программе первая процедура создает новый экземпляр(? надеюсь не ошибся в терминологии) класса disjunct, на основании текущего, а перегрузка оператора = должна присвоить его переменной d3. Ошибка возникает когда я пытаюсь присвоить значение d3 = d2.construct_resolution(d1, g);

```
disjunct disjunct::construct_resolution(disjunct& right_disj, signed char &kontrar_couple){

    disjunct *resolution = new disjunct;

    std::list<signed char>::const_iterator left_it;

    for(left_it = disj.begin(); left_it != disj.end(); left_it++){

        signed char literal = *left_it;
        signed char not_literal = kontrar_couple | 0x80;
        if((literal != kontrar_couple) && (literal != not_literal)){
            resolution->addLiteral(literal);
        }

    }

    return resolution;

}

disjunct& disjunct::operator =(disjunct& disj){

    if (this == &disj) {
            return *this;
        }

    *this->clear();
    std::list<signed char>::iterator i;

    for(i = disj.disj.begin(); i != disj.disj.end(); i++){
        signed char literal = *i;
        *this->addLiteral(literal);
    }

    return *this;

}
```

В функции main пишу:

```
    disjunct d1;
    disjunct d2;
    disjunct d3;

    d3 = d2.construct_resolution(d1, g);
    // g - переменная типа signed char, (является контрарной парой для d2 и d1)
```

получаю ошибку:

> main.cpp:54:39: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘d3 = disjunct::construct_resolution(disjunct&, signed char&)((* & d1), (* & g))’
>   main.cpp:54:39: note: candidate is:
>   disjunct.h:29:15: note: disjunct& disjunct::operator=(disjunct&)
>   disjunct.h:29:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘disjunct’ to ‘disjunct&’

Comment: Да, переписал так, все заработало.
   disjunct& disjunct::operator =(disjunct disj){

    if (this == &disj) {
            return *this;
        }
    
    clear();
    std::list<signed char>::iterator i;
    
    for(i = disj.disj.begin(); i != disj.disj.end(); i++){
        signed char literal = *i;
        addLiteral(literal);
    }
    
    return *this;

}    

Могли бы вы пояснить теоретическую часть. Почему в данном случае по ссылке передавать не нужно? 
**P.S.** странно что мой g++ этом месте ошибок не выдавал )

Comment: @alexlz, спасибо вам, переведите свой комментарий в ответ и я отмечу его как принятый

Comment: А зачем его по ссылке? Вполне себе правая часть присваивания.
А почему не ругается на `return resolution;` в construct_resolution -- непонятно, ведь возвращаемое значение д.б. disjunct&, а resolution -- *disjunct. И с приоритетами операций `*` и `->` тоже не всё "интуитивно понятно"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему

```
disjunct& disjunct::operator =(disjunct& disj){
```

а не

```
disjunct& disjunct::operator =(disjunct disj){
```

Кстати, там ещё зачем-то `*this->`. Это что должно означать? У меня g++ такого не ест